# Adding a 2.5" SSD to a Fujitsu PRIMERGY TX1310 M1

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

The Fujitsu Primergy TX1310 M1 is only listed as having four 3.5" drive bays in all it's documentation, however within the case there is also an extra bays that is slightly smaller and does not come with the Quick Release ("Easy Rails") required to mount a drive there.

This extra bay has "HDD 3" stamped into the sheet metal of the case and can be seen within the internal view (the one without a drive installed).

It looks like it should be big enough for a 2.5" SSD however there are no part numbers listed on the Fujitsu website for this particular model.  Can an SSD be installed within there? And what is the correct part number for the smaller Quick Relase rails?

[image: Internal Image of Fujitsu Primergy TX1310 M1]

```
 ____________________
|             |______|
|             |______|
|             |______|
|             |_HDD5_|
|             |_HDD4_|
|                    |
|____________________|
|_HDD3_|_HDD2_|_HDD1_|
```

Comment: I've created this question and answer combo as I was unable to find an answer to this online before ordering the parts and trying.  Hopefully, if anyone else has the same idea in the future that they can find this for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the part number for the quick release rail is "C26361-K10-B211" (two are required).  Please be aware that Fujitsu sometimes wrongly list "C26361-K10-B21" as equivalent.

The image below shows the 2.5" Quick Release rails fitted with an SSD.

[image: Internal View of TX1310 with SSD]